# Setting css3 transform property with jQuery, += and -= support

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using this jquery plugin to use CSS transforms with the jquery CSS function:

http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/22/jquery-patch-css-transform.html

```
$('.element').css{ transform : 'translate(' + val + 'px,0)' };
```

The above code currently works, but I would like to be able to *increment* the value, like you can do, for example, with margin left:

```
$('.element').css{ marginLeft : '+=' + val };
```

Is there a way to use jquery to increment the css3 transform / translate property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add [css hook](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/) for `translate` and use

`$('.element').css({ translate : '+=' + val });`